# Validity of an Indian 3 year undergrad degree in the U.S

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I am doing B.Sc (Hons.) Mathematics from University of Delhi, India. The duration of the course is three years. I am looking forward to get a MS or a MS + Ph.D. from the states in Pure or Applied Mathematics. So far,I know that validity of degree is subject to course and University. Do the following Universities consider a 3 year undergrad for their MS or a MS + Ph.D. in Maths?

1. MIT
2. Stanford
3. Harvard
4. Ivy leagues

P.S : I know I can get a MS in India and then apply for a Ph.D. from the states.But I would like to know about this so as to plan accordingly.

Comment: Have you contacted those universities and asked them?

Comment: Ya. I did so. I am just waiting for a reply from maths dept. of MIT. Meanwhile I thought to inquire about it from here.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MIT](https://odge.mit.edu/gpp/registration/status/international-student/):

> Graduate student applicants, who are not citizens or permanent
>   residents of the US, must have a bachelor’s degree or its equivalent
>   from a college, university, or technical institute of acceptable
>   standing.

Therefore, if your undergraduate degree is a legitimate degree, then yes, you can apply for those programs. However, it does not guarantee acceptance.

I'd imagine the same applies to just about any graduate program in the US.

Comment: The fact the Bachelor's degree of US is of 4 years while a typical Indian one is of 3 years brings the confusion. Some of them do some of them don't. If someone belongs to these universities could help, that will be really nice.

Comment: I don't think length of study matters that much. A Bachelors degree is a Bachelors degree (assuming it's legitimate). I got my Bachelors in less than 4 years and it's just as legitimate as someone who spent 7 years getting their's.

Comment: It does. Many of them require basic 16 years of education (10+2+4) for graduate admissions.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't think I've seen that before. Not really fair for child geniuses then (not me).

Comment: Yeah. In my case it;s (10+2+3) 15 years. So I am not sure whether they'll consider me or not.

Comment: @yasir What do your three numbers represent? I would spell mine out as 13+3: public school and then college.